# Cisco CSR1000v .iso on GCP

Tags: iso, cisco

I have a Cisco Cloud Service Router 1000v, CSR1000, .iso image that is advertised to run on KVM.  On Google Compute Platform, GCP, I launched a linux 1 vCPU, 0.6 GB VM w assigned public IP and default private IP and uploaded the image.

I was able to mount it and see the `boot` and `boot.catalog` files.

```
[ron@csr1000 ~]$ sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
[ron@csr1000 ~]$ sudo mount -t iso9660 -o loop csr1000v-universalk9.03.11.00.S.154-1.S-std.iso /mnt/tmp
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only

[ron@csr1000 ~]$ sudo cd /mnt/tmp
[ron@csr1000 ~]$ sudo ls -a
. .bash_history .bash_profile csr1000v-universalk9.03.11.00.S.154-1.S-std.iso
.. .bash_logout .bashrc .ssh
[ron@csr1000 ~]$ dir
csr1000v-universalk9.03.11.00.S.154-1.S-std.iso

[ron@csr1000 ~]$ cd /mnt/tmp
[ron@csr1000 tmp]$ ls -a
.  ..  boot  boot.catalog
```

Then modified /etc/fstab to tell the box to boot the CSR .iso upon startup.

```
[ron@csr1000 ~]$ sudo su -
Last login: Mon Oct 31 20:56:18 UTC 2016 on pts/0
[root@csr1000 ~]# ls -l /etc/fstab
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 318 Oct 31 20:58 /etc/fstab
[root@csr1000 ~]# vi /etc/fstab

i
    /home/ron/csr1000v-universalk9.03.11.00.S.154-1.S-std.iso /mnt/tmp iso9660 loop 0 0
enter
ctrl-c
esc
:w
:q

[root@csr1000 ~]# reboot
```

...and still nothing.

Do I need to stand up a virtual serial port?

[Cisco CSR 1000v Series Cloud Services Router Software Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/configuration/csr1000Vswcfg.pdf) indicates a vert-install command but I can't find it...?

Comment: Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [Unix.SE], [SU], or [SF].

Comment: In case anyone else finds this.  CGP does not support running VM's on their VM's.  Also, they don't support the CSR1000v custom instance (as far as I can figure).  Good new is you can stand it up on AWS.  See https://rack.pub/guides/csr100v-on-aws-ec2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then modified /etc/fstab to tell the box to boot the CSR .iso upon startup.

No, that doesn't boot it, it just tells the OS to mount to `.iso` image on `/mnt/tmp`.

If the image runs on KVM, you should look into running it with `qemu`. Note that nested virtualization is not supported by most cloud computing environments, so you may be limited to software emulation.